# Counting individual groups of data

Tags: sql

For the given table

```
1st column=producer
2nd column=type

A a
A a
A a
A b

B c
B c
B c
```

I want to count amount of non repeating groups.
The output should be equal to `A=2 B=1`.

I have no idea how this can be done :(

Comment: Really? No idea? Not even a `SELECT` statement to start from?  (We like to see you at least try something first.)

Comment: I see no point showing quarries far from result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `count()`:

```
select producer, count(distinct type)
from yourtable
group by producer
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 select producer, count(distinct type) from table group by  producer
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
SELECT producer, COUNT(DISTINCT type)
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY producer
```

This should give you a result similar to this:

```
producer  COUNT(DISTINCT type)
--------  --------------------
A         2
B         1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT producer, COUNT(producer)
FROM table
GROUP BY producer, type
```